# Calculate SMA_Close10 and SMA_Close20 of minute data

Tags: sql, sqlite

I calculate SMA(10) using last 9 bars Close + current Close. I have done it in Google Sheet and this is the correct values I also get in my trading platform.

```
Date    Time    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  SMA_Close10 SMA_Close20
2022-01-02  18:01:00    17535.75    17601   17535.75    17564.25    1024    #REF!   #REF!
2022-01-02  18:02:00    17562.25    17578.5 17560.75    17573.25    610 #REF!   #REF!
2022-01-02  18:03:00    17573.25    17579.25    17566   17566.75    347 #REF!   #REF!
2022-01-02  18:04:00    17566.5 17568.75    17563   17565   206 #REF!   #REF!
2022-01-02  18:05:00    17564.25    17567.75    17558.5 17565   257 #REF!   #REF!
2022-01-02  18:06:00    17565   17570.5 17563.25    17567.5 283 #REF!   #REF!
2022-01-02  18:07:00    17567.25    17573.75    17566.75    17573   141 #REF!   #REF!
2022-01-02  18:08:00    17573.25    17574.25    17567   17568.25    209 #REF!   #REF!
2022-01-02  18:09:00    17568.5 17571.5 17564.25    17566.25    261 17567.69    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:10:00    17565   17565   17552.5 17557   342 17566.63    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:11:00    17557.5 17558.5 17555   17557   83  17565.90    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:12:00    17557   17562   17556   17559.25    162 17564.50    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:13:00    17558.5 17559.75    17556.75    17558.25    56  17563.65    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:14:00    17558.5 17558.75    17552.25    17554.25    160 17562.58    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:15:00    17555.25    17555.25    17552.25    17552.25    68  17561.30    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:16:00    17552   17559.75    17551.5 17559.5 103 17560.50    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:17:00    17558.75    17560.25    17556.75    17559.5 122 17559.15    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:18:00    17559.75    17564.5 17559.75    17564   179 17558.73    #REF!
2022-01-02  18:19:00    17563.75    17564.25    17561.75    17564   50  17558.50    17562.86
2022-01-02  18:20:00    17564.25    17565.25    17561.5 17562   70  17559.00    17562.81
2022-01-02  18:21:00    17562.5 17562.5 17560.5 17561.5 59  17559.45    17562.68
2022-01-02  18:22:00    17561.5 17563   17556.75    17562.25    112 17559.75    17562.13
2022-01-02  18:23:00    17562   17567.75    17562   17563.25    168 17560.25    17561.95
2022-01-02  18:24:00    17564   17564   17559   17559.75    90  17560.80    17561.69
2022-01-02  18:25:00    17560   17560.25    17557.25    17558.75    86  17561.45    17561.38
2022-01-02  18:26:00    17558.5 17558.5 17550.5 17551.5 186 17560.65    17560.58
2022-01-02  18:27:00    17550.75    17556   17550.75    17555.5 76  17560.25    17559.70
2022-01-02  18:28:00    17555.5 17556.5 17554   17554   38  17559.25    17558.99
2022-01-02  18:29:00    17554.5 17558.75    17551.5 17558.25    85  17558.68    17558.59
2022-01-02  18:30:00    17558.5 17560.5 17557.25    17559.75    73  17558.45    17558.73
2022-01-02  18:31:00    17560.25    17561   17554.75    17556   123 17557.90    17558.68
2022-01-02  18:32:00    17556.5 17556.75    17554   17555.25    70  17557.20    17558.48
2022-01-02  18:33:00    17555   17555   17549   17550   108 17555.88    17558.06
2022-01-02  18:34:00    17551   17552.25    17549.75    17551.25    72  17555.03    17557.91
2022-01-02  18:35:00    17552.25    17554.75    17552.25    17554   79  17554.55    17558.00
2022-01-02  18:36:00    17554.5 17554.75    17551.25    17551.5 46  17554.55    17557.60
2022-01-02  18:37:00    17551.5 17555.75    17551.5 17555   41  17554.50    17557.38
2022-01-02  18:38:00    17554.5 17557.25    17552.75    17553.5 76  17554.45    17556.85
2022-01-02  18:39:00    17553.5 17557   17553   17555.5 64  17554.18    17556.43
2022-01-02  18:40:00    17555.75    17557.25    17555.25    17556.5 35  17553.85    17556.15
2022-01-02  18:41:00    17556.25    17556.25    17552.25    17555   74  17553.75    17555.83
2022-01-02  18:42:00    17555.25    17556   17554.75    17556   25  17553.83    17555.51
2022-01-02  18:43:00    17555.75    17555.75    17553.5 17553.75    34  17554.20    17555.04
2022-01-02  18:44:00    17554.5 17557.25    17554.5 17556.5 41  17554.73    17554.88
2022-01-02  18:45:00    17556.75    17557.75    17556.25    17557   32  17555.03    17554.79
2022-01-02  18:46:00    17557   17561.25    17556   17556.75    119 17555.55    17555.05
2022-01-02  18:47:00    17556.25    17559.25    17555.25    17559.25    61  17555.98    17555.24
2022-01-02  18:48:00    17558.5 17560   17558   17559   49  17556.53    17555.49
2022-01-02  18:49:00    17559   17559.75    17558   17559.75    27  17556.95    17555.56
2022-01-02  18:50:00    17559.5 17563   17559.5 17561.75    148 17557.48    17555.66
2022-01-02  18:51:00    17561.75    17562.5 17559.5 17559.75    44  17557.95    17555.85
2022-01-02  18:52:00    17559.5 17561.25    17559   17561.25    39  17558.48    17556.15
2022-01-02  18:53:00    17561   17563   17561   17562.5 51  17559.35    17556.78
2022-01-02  18:54:00    17563.25    17564.5 17562.5 17564.25    74  17560.13    17557.43
2022-01-02  18:55:00    17564   17564.75    17563.5 17564   27  17560.83    17557.93
2022-01-02  18:56:00    17563.75    17563.75    17560.75    17562.75    98  17561.43    17558.49
2022-01-02  18:57:00    17562.25    17563.5 17562.25    17563   29  17561.80    17558.89
2022-01-02  18:58:00    17563   17563   17561   17561.75    37  17562.08    17559.30
2022-01-02  18:59:00    17562.25    17567.75    17562.25    17566.5 126 17562.75    17559.85
2022-01-02  19:00:00    17565.5 17566.25    17563.25    17563.5 56  17562.93    17560.20
2022-01-02  19:01:00    17564   17570.75    17564   17564.75    155 17563.43    17560.69
2022-01-02  19:02:00    17565.5 17568.5 17565.5 17566.75    69  17563.98    17561.23
2022-01-02  19:03:00    17567.75    17570.25    17566.75    17568.5 103 17564.58    17561.96
2022-01-02  19:04:00    17568.25    17573   17567   17569   109 17565.05    17562.59
2022-01-02  19:05:00    17569.25    17570.5 17567   17568.25    75  17565.48    17563.15
2022-01-02  19:06:00    17567.5 17571   17567.5 17568.5 55  17566.05    17563.74
2022-01-02  19:07:00    17569   17570.5 17569   17570   33  17566.75    17564.28
2022-01-02  19:08:00    17570   17570.25    17567   17568.5 48  17567.43    17564.75
2022-01-02  19:09:00    17567.5 17567.5 17566   17566.75    66  17567.45    17565.10
2022-01-02  19:10:00    17566.75    17571   17566.75    17571   79  17568.20    17565.56
2022-01-02  19:11:00    17571   17572   17569.75    17572   95  17568.93    17566.18
2022-01-02  19:12:00    17571.75    17572.75    17570.25    17571   75  17569.35    17566.66
2022-01-02  19:13:00    17570.5 17570.5 17566.75    17566.75    93  17569.18    17566.88
2022-01-02  19:14:00    17567.5 17567.75    17565.5 17566.5 38  17568.93    17566.99
2022-01-02  19:15:00    17566.75    17567.25    17564.25    17565   68  17568.60    17567.04
2022-01-02  19:16:00    17565.25    17569.5 17564   17568.5 109 17568.60    17567.33



WITH Calculations AS (
    SELECT
        Date,
        Time,
        Close,
        CASE 
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time) >= 10 THEN 
                AVG(Close) OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
            ELSE NULL
        END AS SMA_Close10,
        CASE 
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time) >= 20 THEN 
                AVG(Close) OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time ROWS BETWEEN 19 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
            ELSE NULL
        END AS SMA_Close20
    FROM
        NQ_06_24_1_Minute
)

UPDATE NQ_06_24_1_Minute
SET 
    SMA_Close10 = CASE WHEN Calculations.SMA_Close10 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Calculations.SMA_Close10 END,
    SMA_Close20 = CASE WHEN Calculations.SMA_Close20 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Calculations.SMA_Close20 END
FROM
    Calculations
WHERE
    NQ_06_24_1_Minute.Date = Calculations.Date
    AND NQ_06_24_1_Minute.Time = Calculations.Time;
```

What do I need to fix on the code to calculate skip the first rows (only when I have enough data) I should start calculate SMA_Close10 and SMA_Close20?

[image]